# Using headroom.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use headroom.js in my footer but i isn't working. The HTML is just a normal code where .PageList is my footer

CSS: to make my footer sticking to the bottom of the page

```
.PageList {
   background: #fff;
   bottom: -15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   padding-top: 10px;
   color: #000;
   width: 790px;
   position:fixed;
   z-index:99999;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Javascript to get the headroom working. But it isn't working:

```
(function() {
    var header = new Headroom(document.querySelector(&quot;.PageList&quot;), {
        tolerance: 5,
        offset : 205,
    });
    header.init();
}());
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function needs to run **after** the HTML parser has seen the elements with `class=PageList`. Eg., include the `<script>` after the footer, or use the `defer` attribute on the `<script>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a bug with how you entered the code in here, but the headroom variable should look like:

```
var headroom  = new Headroom(document.querySelector(".PageList") , {
    tolerance: 5,
    offset : 205,
});
```

for example